# How much cost/rounds does Laravel use to hash with?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to understand how the below function works from Laravel 4.2 in the BcryptHasher.php file:

```
/**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function make($value, array $options = [])
    {
        $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

        $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);

        if ($hash === false) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Bcrypt hashing not supported.');
        }

        return $hash;
    }
```

I think I understand everything except for this line:

```
$cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;
```

I understand that the default of $this->rounds is set to 10, which then is the "cost" that the password will be hashed at.  However, I'm confused as to what the $options array is doing and how that might affect the cost?

Comment: If the $options array is set (by the user calling the method), then use the value obtained by $options['rounds'] as the $cost instead of $this->rounds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass in the options when you call the `make` method.

For example, using the facade:

```
$hashed = Hash::make($value, ['rounds' => 8]);
```

If you don't pass in the `cost`, it'll use `$this->rounds`, which is `10`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for Laravel 4.2, but for 5.7 the option is not `cost`, but `rounds`. So it would look like `$hashed = Hash::make($value, ['rounds' => 8]);`

Answer (score 2):

in laravel 5.5 and before, because the hash rounds number is hardcoded in these versions, there is no way, unless you build a facade or service to handle having default hashing rounds number based on what you desire and then use your wrapper class instead of the original Hash class.

But, Since laravel 5.6, the default hashing rounds number is stored in the `config/hashing.php` file and you can change the default to what you desire using this section or setting the `BCRYPT_ROUNDS` environment variable in your `.env` file.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bcrypt Options
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the configuration options that should be used when
| passwords are hashed using the Bcrypt algorithm. This will allow you
| to control the amount of time it takes to hash the given password.
|
*/

'bcrypt' => [
    'rounds' => env('BCRYPT_ROUNDS', 10),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a complement to [adnan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084420), in laravel ^10 they changed the default bcrypt rounds from 10 to 12 ([check pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48494)).
So:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Bcrypt Options
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the configuration options that should be used when
    | passwords are hashed using the Bcrypt algorithm. This will allow you
    | to control the amount of time it takes to hash the given password.
    |
    */

    'bcrypt' => [
        'rounds' => env('BCRYPT_ROUNDS', 12),
        'verify' => true,
    ],
```